# How to substitute a match at random positions instead of from left to right using regex?

Tags: python, python-re

My goal is to match a query in a string and substitute it using regex.sub, but the program is;
a) not searching the string from left to right, rather searching randomly
b) substituting every occurrence.

My example:

```
input = "AAAAAAAAAA"
query_left = "AA"
query_right = "AA"
output = re.sub(r"(%s)(%s)" % (query_left, query_right), r"\1 \2", input)
```

This gives `"AA AAAA AAAA"` as output, because it matches the first four characters `("**AAAA**AAAAAA")` and introduces a space in the middle.
Then it matches the next four `("AAAA**AAAA**AA")` and introduces a space and then it cannot find another match because the following two As are too short.
I tackled problem `b) (actually substituting every occurrence)` just by executing the substitution two times after one another:

```
output1 = re.sub(r"(%s)(%s)" % (query_left, query_right), r"\1 \2", input)
output2 = re.sub(r"(%s)(%s)" % (query_left, query_right), r"\1 \2", output1)
```

which gives `"AA AA AA AA AA"` as output2 which is my intent but which seems not the most elegant solution to me.
Does someone have a better suggestion?

A bigger challenge is problem `a), searching the string randomly for the match and then replacing`. 
What I want in the end is an output with a certain randomness that looks like `"AAA AA AA AAA"` or `"AA AAA AA AAA"` or `"AA AAA AAA AA"` etc., so a string where `"AAAA"` has been replaced at random positions with `"AA AA"` until no `"AAAA"` sequences are left to be matched. 
Does someone have any idea how to implement this?

Comment: For b) its returning `'AA AA'` then another `'AA AA'`  then `'AA'` with no spacing between any of these strings. Why not just put a space at the end of your replication? i.e. `output = re.sub(r"(%s)(%s)" % (query_left, query_right), r"\1 \2 ", input)` returns `'AA AA AA AA AA'`